# Only partial support for C++11 in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, c++11

I got Netbeans 7.4 installed today with supports for PHP, Java, and C++.
However, it seems that I only have partial support for C++11 (even with GCC 4.8.1 with `-std=c++11 or -std=C++0x`).

I've looked at the header files (e.g. chrono) and there's a inlined namespace named _V2 that follows the following comments :

```
// To support the (forward) evolution of the library's defined
// clocks, wrap inside inline namespace so that the current
// defintions of system_clock, steady_clock, and
// high_resolution_clock types are uniquely mangled. This way, new
// code can use the latests clocks, while the library can contain
// compatibility definitions for previous versions.  At some
// point, when these clocks settle down, the inlined namespaces
// can be removed.  XXX GLIBCXX_ABI Deprecated
```

So, for instance, if I want to use high_resolution_clock, I need

```
chrono::_V2::high_resolution_clock
```

Instead of

```
chrono::high_resolution_clock
```

Also to_string from string is also declared as undefined.

Am I missing somethng? Do I have to update my headers in Netbeans? If so, may I ask you to advise me on how to proceed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Names inside `inline namespace`s are automatically lifted to the parent namespace, so there should be no need to specify `::_V2`. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Did you install Netbeans bundled with gcc? What build system do you use?

Comment: I switched to Debian and I'm using KDevelop now. It's working like a charm!